# Does Shape Dynamics use Space relationalism?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-physics, physics, space

(Already posted this on Physics Stack Exchange, hope it's okay)

On Wikipedia it says [Shape dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_dynamics) is an implementation of [Space relationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationalism#Relationalism_(theory_of_space_and_time)) however I don't see how this can be true.

In general relativity gravity exists thanks to Space substantivalism, the fact Spacetime is a kind of an aether that curves and its existence is independent from objects in it.

If Shape dynamics uses Relationalism instead of [Container space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_space) how does gravity work?

Comment: Gravity needs spacetime substantivalism no more than electromagnetism needs aether. Moreover, substantivalism in GR is largely vitiated by the [hole argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-holearg/#UnhCon) and was disclaimed by Einstein himself. But shape dynamics is an alternative to GR, so it does not have to be sustantivalist even if GR was. It is, in fact, relational (and satisfies the Mach principle). For details on how gravity works there see [SEP, Shape Dynamics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/#ShapDyna).

Comment: @Conifold I guess I don't understand what causes gravity in Shape dynamics. In GR it is caused by spacetime curvature, what is it in Shape dynamics?

Comment: Well, what causes electromagnetic and other self-propagating fields in gauge theories in the absence of aether? As I understand it, gravity and inertia are caused by dynamical interactions between different parts of matter (in the spirit of Mach's principle). Spacetime and its curvature are macrostructures that emerge as a result of them, not their causes.

Comment: Photons exist because there is quantum Electromagnetic field, however in Shape dynamics as I understood it there are no Gravitons and quantum Gravitational field

Comment: There are no photons in classical electrodynamics or other classical gauge theories, and GR is not a quantum theory either. You can rewrite both without fields, in terms of relational interactions between pieces of (ordinary) matter. Those interactions will then be the "causes", and fields will be emergent structures that can be used to describe them globally. How this can be quantized is an open question even for GR, but SD uses Lagrangian framework, which is typically more amenable to quantization.